# What's the technical term for the period of time between when an opponent concludes their turn and mine begins?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Apologies if this is poorly phrased.  I'll try to make this as clear as possible...

I recently realized that I can utilize the period of time between a players turn and my turn in Magic. What's the name of this period?  What is the appropriate verbiage/ettiquette to indicate doing something during that time? I don't think its "during your upkeep"...

Essentially, I'd like to use this time to activate lands like [Arid Mesa](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arid%20Mesa) search my library for land that I want without losing a cycle doing that.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [basic rulebook](http://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/EN_Magic_Basic_Rulebook_20090710.pdf). In particular for this question, page 16 explains the phases/steps of a turn. But there might be other things in there you haven't realized too!

Comment: "I'd like to use this time to activate lands like Arid Mesa search my library for land that I want without losing a cycle doing that." If by "cycle" you mean "the ability to play a land once on each of your turns", don't worry; using Arid Mesa's ability doesn't count towards that. You can use its ability without consuming your "land drop" for the turn.

Comment: There are reasons to do it that way though. For example, if you have both a Steam Vents and a Hallowed Fountain in your deck, you may want to wait as long as possible to decide which to get, but you also want to get them before your next untap step so that you don't have to pay the 2 life to untap them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no **between** turns; the end of one turn transitions immediately to the beginning of the next. The last time you can definitely activate abilities and play instants before your turn is during your opponent's [End Step](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/End_of_turn_step), which is after their second main phase. The end step is is followed by the cleanup step (the last step of the turn), when players usually *do not* gain priority, and that is followed immediately by your untap step.

The standard way of indicating that you want to do something during this time is to wait for your opponent to say "I end my turn." (or equivalent), and then you say "During your end step, I activate my Arid Mesa's ability."

Technically, this falls under the [Shortcut rules](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Shortcut). The [official tournament rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_2jun14_en.pdf) (section 4.2) list "Your turn" (and equivalents) as meaning "I propose a shortcut: that I pass priority until you have priority at my end step" and when you say "I would like to do something at your end step" it means "I accept your shortcut, and when it is complete I do something."

Comment: It is worth noting that there is no time to take actions between turns. There is only priority during the End Step of each turn.

Comment: I tried to explain that with "[the cleanup step] is followed immediately by your untap step." Was that unclear?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the second sentence, actually (...the last time you will be able to do so..."). But sometimes it is also worth explicitly addressing the phrasing in the question. It sounds like the OP thought the turn ended at the end of the second main phase, but it doesn't: it's followed by the end step (and the cleanup step), which are part of the turn, not between turns.

Comment: Do you think it's clearer now?

Comment: Personally, I'd like to see it made explicit - like, as the very first sentence, "There is no time between turns." But I don't think it's important enough to warrant writing my own answer (which would otherwise be much the same as yours).

Comment: Do you think this is better?

Comment: I believe your last paragraph is misleading. Untapping your lands and creatures would be the same as saying "I accept your shortcut." If you say "During your end step..." that would be the same as saying "I decline your shortcut." and the game actually goes as it is supposed to without shortcuts.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the shortcut jumps to when he has priority at the end of his opponent's endstep, and since he's activating an ability when he has priority at his opponent's end step, he has accepted the shortcut.

Comment: @murgatroid99 (3 comments up) yes, I like what you did with your latest edit.

Comment: @corsika Saying "During your end step" is *not* declining the shortcut. **Declining** the shortcut would be more like "Please play out the remainder of your phases." **Shortcutting** the shortcut would be like "I'll take priority in your second main phase." **Accepting** the shortcut is like "During your end step, I'll do X." Untapping *also* means "I accept your shortcut, and then I pass." Passing in the end step progresses the game to the untap step. Most players are not so verbal about it, but you don't really need to consult your opponent to pass, right?

Comment: @VolleyJosh, players can gain priority during the Cleanup Step if a triggered ability manages to occur at that time (for example, discarding one of the legendary Eldrazi when you discard down to your maximum hand size). It's an exceptional occurrence, but it does happen (in fact, it will _always_ happen for Thawing Glaciers' delayed trigger)

Comment: Agreed, but still it is not 'between turns', which, based on the questions & headline's phrasing is worth noting. I like the current wording.

Comment: @Rusher passing the end step passes to the cleanup step where players can get priority to respond to events occuring as a result of the cleanup step (for example "when this card enters the graveyard" triggering from discarding down to 7. After the cleanup is the untap step where no priority is given ("when this uptaps" and other such triggers are deferred to the beginning of the upkeep step). I think you (and murgatroid) are oversimplifying exactly how complex the 'go' shortcut really is and what it entails, which I suppose is okay given mugatroid's link to the shortcut rules.

Comment: @corsiKa I don't think I'm simplifying the shortcut. The rules I linked define the shortcut exactly as I did in my answer, and I stand by saying that everything in my answer and comments works exactly as I said. I just made a minor edit to clarify my second sentence.

Comment: Interesting. After reading the article, I've found the confusion. You weren't oversimplifying. I was overcomplicated. I would have considered the one "Go" shortcut to be what you consider two different shortcuts. One by player A who passes priority until B gets priority in the end step, and then a shortcut initiated by B to pass any cleanup and untap-deferred triggers and proceed with the upkeep step. I would have considered those two different, but it appears I'm in the minority.

Comment: @corsiKa In your description, when player B passes priority in player A's end step, play usually automatically proceeds to player A having priority in their upkeep because cleanup triggers are rare and untap-deferred triggers are on the stack as expected when that state is reached. There is no need for a shortcut here because the only non-turn-based action here is a single passing of priority.